# Calling a function twice?

Tags: javascript, pug

```
Jade.compileFile(layout, { pretty: false })(locals);
```

Can someone explain this code?

I know that this code line uses Jade Template Engine method `compileFile`. `layout` is a source path, `pretty` is an option passed to `compileFile`. `locals` is an object.

Is this function called twice or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form the [Jade docs](http://jade-lang.com/api/) on .compileFile():

> Returns A function to generate the html from an object containing locals

In mose JS templating engines there is a compile function that parses the original template string, and returns a template function.

When the function is invoked with the data (locals) it returns an HTML string that includes the data.

Code example from Jade docs:

var jade = require('jade');

```
// Compile a function
var fn = jade.compileFile('path to jade file', options);

// Render the function
var html = fn(locals);
// => '<string>of jade</string>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I did not see dat compileFile returns function my eye was constantly on jade.compileClient wich returns string.

Comment: Welcome - the api docs design is calling for such mistakes :)

Answer (score 3):

The `Jade.compileFile` method returns a separate function which is then called with the argument `locals`.

To demonstrate this, you could alternately write:

```
var func = Jade.compileFile(layout, { pretty: false });
func(locals);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the Jade Template Engine but the first call seems to return a function. The returned function is then called with a locals parameter. Sorry if it is not the right answer.